# Using OR to set parameters inside conditional | Powershell 5

Tags: powershell

Essentially I need to start my conditional using by implying 3 different conditions.

If the exit code is 1 or 2 or 3 they script must do something if anything else do something else:

```
if ( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 1 or $LASTEXITCODE -eq 2 or $LASTEXITCODE -eq 3 or  ) {

}
```

What is the correct syntax for the code above?

Comment: `-or` is the operator. Use an `else` statement for the ***other*** condition

Comment: So my sample code is correct just put a dash in front of the or?

Comment: Your code will do the condition if $`lastexitcode` is 1, 2, or 3. Is this intended or were you looking for `elseif`?

Comment: Another approach could be `if ( $LASTEXITCODE -ge 1 -and $LASTEXITCODE -le 3)`

Comment: Learn basic powershell.

Answer (score 1):

The logical OR operator in PowerShell is prefixed with `-`, so that would be:

```bsh
if($LASTEXITCODE -eq 1 -or $LASTEXITCODE -eq 2 -or $LASTEXITCODE -eq 3){

}
```

For a more concise way of testing for this condition you would leverage the `-contains` or `-in` containment operators:

```bsh
if($LASTEXITCODE -in 1,2,3){ ... }
# or 
if(1,2,3 -contains $LASTEXITCODE){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If $LastExitCode is always greater than 0 you could just use:

```
If ($LastExitCode -lt 4)  {#do for 1,2,3}
Else (#do for 4+}
```

If $LastExitCode could be zero:

```
Switch ($LASTEXITCODE) {
   0                   {"Zero"}
   {1..3 -Contains $_} {"Range 1-3"}
   Default             {"Greater than 3"}
}
```

HTH

Comment: Careful, this would also evaluate to `$true` for `$LASTEXITCODE = 1` :)